# How to improve distance calculation on SQL

Tags: sql, gps

We are trying to get the nearest customer to each of a subset of customers. Our SQL works as expected but even for a small test database (4,000 customers, 50 cust subset) it takes a few seconds, and obviously it increases dramatically as the database size does.

```
select ... custA data, custB data
from customers custA
left join customers custB on custB.id=
     (select custC.id
      from customers custC
      where custC.id<>custA.id
      order by distance(custA.lat,custA.lon,custC.lat,custC.lon) asc limit 1)
where ... custA conditions
```

distance is a function that calculates exactly what it's name suggests :)

For sure, we can search some kind of filter so to compare only customers of same state or similar ... or put a maximum on diference of lat or lon ... etc, but is there any way to improve the sql structure?

Thks

Answer (score 0):

I have a suggestion to your problem.  I am using a table variable to mimic your Customers table and a filled with dummy data.  For simplicity reasons I removed the usage of the distance function but you can easily replace in your environment.

I am taking advantage of the ROW_NUMBER to replace your inner query with the TOP 1

My solution is written for SQL Server:

```
create table customers (
    id int identity(1,1),
    distance int
)
go


insert into customers values(10)
insert into customers values(100)
insert into customers values(20)
insert into customers values(30)
insert into customers values(40)
insert into customers values(50)
insert into customers values(60)
go

create view AllCustomerDistances with SCHEMABINDING 
as
select custA.Id custA_Id, custC.Id custC_id, custA.distance - custC.distance [distanceBetweenAandC] --distance(custA.lat, custA.lon, custC.lon, custC.lon) [distanceBetweenAandC]
from 
    dbo.customers custA cross join
    dbo.customers custC
where
    custA.Id <> custC.Id

go

select *
from
(   select
        custA.Id [A],
        custB.Id [B],
        row_number() over (partition by custA_Id  order by distanceBetweenAandC desc) as Rownumber
    from
    AllCustomerDistances d inner join 
        customers custA on (d.custA_Id = custA.Id) inner join
        customers custb on (d.custC_Id = custb.Id)
) r
where
    Rownumber = 1
```

My subquery calculates the distances between all customers and the row_number function allows me to order by distance and select only the smaller combination.

EDIT:  I am now using a view to calculate the distances and have it store in sql server.  Using WITH SCHEMABINDING option will allow sql server to pre-process the view so, multiple calls to the view will result in a much faster query.  The impact happens the first time you run your query.  The view will view updated automatically when the referenced records change.

Comment: Thanks for the interesting idea, although it doesn't improve our initial syntax. We tested it and it takes between 1.6 and 1.8 times of the original ... as the subset of customers to match increases, the relation gets worse and worse.

Comment: I edited my answer and now it is using an Indexed View.  I am not sure if this can be used in your case but what may be killing your query is the amount of time it takes to calculate the distance between customers every time you run your query.  with an indexed view this will happen when the view is materialized the first time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We are using a Postgress database and the most similar concept would be a MATERIALIZED view. A materialized view must be rebuild explicitly with a periodic process as the view data is not updated when the source tables are. Unsure about the time reuired to build the whole view on a production system as it will contain milions of records (a cross join of all customer table with itself) ... We will give it a try.

Comment: A second though ... if we have to rebuild the view and not have real data there is no need to store all possible values, we can already store only the nearest customer as a result of our initial query. Simpler and faster.
We were looking for a better on-line solution ... but thanks anyway.